# Why does PCA geom_point shape include factors not specify?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I would like to do a PCA with eclipse added. However I realized that when I try to specify group as shape, ggplot will add group in addition to what I used for the eclipse. Here is an example.

```
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

iris$group = ifelse ( iris$Sepal.Length > 5, "high", "low")

p = fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label="none"
             , habillage=iris$Species
             ,addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95)


p +geom_point(aes(shape= factor(iris$group ) ) )
```

So as you can see I set habillage to species and tried to draw the shape with factor group, but for some reason the shape adds in not only group but species as well.  Ideally what I want is to only have group with shapes high and low.
thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `fviz_pca_ind()` creates aesthetics that are hard to adjust afterwards.

One solution is to stop it from creating the points with aesthetics using `geom.ind`. Then you can add the points back. Finally, you have to use `guides()` to turn off some legend features.

```
p = fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label="none"
                 , habillage=iris$Species
                 , addEllipses=TRUE, 
                geom.ind = c("text"),
                 ellipse.level=0.95) 

 
p + geom_point(aes(shape = factor(iris$group), 
                   color = factor(iris$Species))) +
  guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)
```